# Need help understanding how array_udiff works

Tags: php, arrays

I am having a hard time understanding how `array_udiff()` works in PHP.

I have read some similar posts that where using integers. But my main concern is this.

Based on the code below:

1. How do `array_udiff` know if `$string1` is larger then `$string2`?
2. Whats the point of returning a negative or positive number?

```
$string1 = array("a1" => "John", "b1" => "Mike");
$string2 = array("a1" => "Tony", "b2" => "John");    

function check($string1, $string2){
    if($string1 > $string2){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using your `check()` function `array_udiff()` will think every string is different. `check()` needs to return 3 values - a negative value if `$string1 < $string2`, a positive value if `$string1 > $string2` or zero if they are equal. If you haven't already I would suggest reading the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array_udiff() consider the return 0 or false, in your case means that returns false.
this means that false results will not be taken.
In set theory your question result a(john,mike) - b(tony,john) = a(john,mike) : but this is incomplete.

Trying this to test:

```
$string1 = array("a1" => "John", "b1" => "Mike");
$string2 = array("a1" => "Tony", "b2" => "John");

function check($string1, $string2){
    if($string1 > $string2){
        echo $string1.' &gt '.$string2.' test1<br >';
        return 1;
    }else if($string1 < $string2){
        echo $string1.' &lt '.$string2.' test2<br />';
        return -1;
    }else{
        echo $string1.' - '.$string2.' test3<br />';
        return 0;
    }
}
print_r(array_udiff($string1, $string2, 'check'));

Mike > John test1
John < Tony test2
John - John test3
John < Mike test2
Mike < Tony test2
result: Array ( [b1] => Mike ) 
a(john,mike) - b(tony,john) = a(mike)
```